# MS-Word: how to set a textbox with 100% width of the column in a two-columned document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have the following word coument, in which I would like to fix the position of the two figures  on the right top of the page. Thus I inserted a text box where I want to put the two figures inside. Now my problem is, how can I fix the position of the textbox on the top position of the right column, **and make it of width 100% relative to the right column?** I didn't find the setting for 100% width relative to "**right column**" thing.
[image]

Comment: Is your issue that the margin inside the text box makes it so that the pasted figures don't fill the page margins when you make the text box match the page margins?

Comment: No. I want to make the textbox fit in the right column only (width). I couldn't do it.

Comment: You should be able to use the drag points (corners and middle of sides) to position and size the text box however you want.  What type of problem do you experience when you try to do that?

Comment: Yes I can drag to do that. But I think there may be a standard and more precise way to do that. Like in "Position"->"layout" or somewhere else.

Comment: I usually find that the easiest way to do it is to position it by hand and then check those layout settings to fine-tune it.  It saves all of the mental gymnastics of calculating what all of the settings should be.  Once it is close, it is easy to see how any settings need to be tweaked.

Comment: It does work. Maybe it is the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it is possible to do this in the later versions of Microsoft Word by using shape format positioning. Instructions for the Office 365 desktop version (probably similar for all recent versions):

1. Navigate to: Shape Format > Position > More Layout Options.
2. Select the Size tab on the Layout pop-up.
3. Set the Width as Relative with a value of 100% ([which should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5govG.png)).
4. Hopefully (!) you'll get a [text box which is *precisely* aligned to the current margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgJJO.png) without having to drag the sides.